# Navigation between two ion-views without nav bar

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

I'm using the awesome framework Ionic to build my first application.

I want to be able to navigate between ion views without the need to use a nav bar.

I have page1 and Page2 I can navigate to the page 2 from the page 1 but I can get back to the page 1 from the page 2.

i'm using a simple button to naviate like :

```
<button class="button button-clear button-positive" ui-sref="tab.chats" >go</button>
```

here is my full code : [PLUNKER CODE + DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/1XL6eJtuuAHWdV5955E6?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using your tabs wrong.

Your tabs must be wrapped in a `tabs` directive.

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-item-hide">

  <ion-tab title="dash" href="#/tab/dash">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-dash"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <ion-tab title="chats" href="#/tab/chats">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-chats"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

</ion-tabs>
```

`tabs-item-hide` cause you want to hide them.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/EwKs8GLot6fcPIe41PgV?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how to keep the navigation transition effect ?

Comment: @YasserB.: You hardly accept answer. You hardly up-vote. Why should I bother ??

Comment: @LeftyX +1, Totally agree !

Comment: I'm sorry I just wanted to know more why the slide effect is not working, thanks again :)